# How to merge all contents in two csv files where records match off 1 column

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have two csv files. They both have `SamAccountName` in common. User records may or may not have a match found for every record between both files (THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT TO NOTE).

I am trying to basically just merge all columns (and their values) into one file (based from the SamAccountNames found in the first file...).

If the SamAccountName is not found in the 2nd file, it should add all null values for that user record in the merged file (since the record was found in the first file).

If the SamAccountName is found in the 2nd file, but not in the first, it should ignore merging that record.

Number of columns in each file may vary (5, 10, 2, so forth...).

```
Function MergeTwoCsvFiles
{
    Param ([String]$baseFile, [String]$fileToBeMerged, [String]$columnTitleLineInFileToBeMerged)
    
    $baseFileCsvContents = Import-Csv $baseFile
    $fileToBeMergedCsvContents = Import-Csv $fileToBeMerged
    
    $baseFileContents = Get-Content $baseFile
    
    $baseFileContents[0] += "," + $columnTitleLineInFileToBeMerged
    
    $baseFileCsvContents | ForEach-Object {
        $matchFound = $False
        $baseSameAccountName = $_.SamAccountName
        [String]$mergedLineInFile = $_
        
        [String]$lineMatchFound = $fileToBeMergedCsvContents | Where-Object {$_.SamAccountName -eq $baseSameAccountName}
        Write-Host '$mergedLineInFile =' $mergedLineInFile
        Write-Host '$lineMatchFound =' $lineMatchFound
        Exit
    }
}
```

The problem is, the record in the file is being written as a hash table instead of a string like line (if you were to view it as .txt). So I'm not really sure how to do this...

## Adding results csv example files...

First CSV File

```
"SamAccountName","sn","GivenName"
"PBrain","Pinky","Brain"
"JSteward","John","Steward"
"JDoe","John","Doe"
"SDoo","Scooby","Doo"
```

Second CSV File

```
"SamAccountName","employeeNumber","userAccountControl","mail"
"KYasunori","678213","546","KYasunori@mystuff.com"
"JSteward","43518790","512","JSteward@mystuff.com"
"JKibogabi","24356","546","JKibogabi@mystuff.com"
"JDoe","902187u4","1114624","JDoe@mystuff.com"
"CStrife","54627","512","CStrife@mystuff.com"
```

Expected Merged CSV File

```
"SamAccountName","sn","GivenName","employeeNumber","userAccountControl","mail"
"PBrain","Pinky","Brain","","",""
"JSteward","John","Steward","43518790","512","JSteward@mystuff.com"
"JDoe","John","Doe","902187u4","1114624","JDoe@mystuff.com"
"SDoo","Scooby","Doo","","",""
```

Note: This will be part of a loop process in merging multiple files, so I would like to avoid hardcoding the title names (with `$_.SamAccountName` as an exception)

## Trying suggestion from "restless 1987" (Not Working)

```
$baseFileCsvContents = Import-Csv 'D:\Scripts\Powershell\Tests\base.csv'
$fileToBeMergedCsvContents = Import-Csv 'D:\Scripts\Powershell\Tests\lookup.csv'
$resultsFile = 'D:\Scripts\Powershell\Tests\MergedResults.csv'
$resultsFileContents = @()

$baseFileContents = Get-Content 'D:\Scripts\Powershell\Tests\base.csv'

$recordsMatched = compare-object $baseFileCsvContents $fileToBeMergedCsvContents -Property SamAccountName

switch ($recordsMatched)
{
    '<=' {}
    '=>' {}
    '==' {$resultsFileContents += $_}
}

$resultsFileCsv = $resultsFileContents | ConvertTo-Csv
$resultsFileCsv | Export-Csv $resultsFile -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Output gives a blank file :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below outputs the desired results based on the inputs you provided.

```
function CombineSkip1($s1, $s2){
    $s3 = $s1 -split ',' 
    $s2 -split ',' | select -Skip 1 | % {$s3 += $_}
    $s4 = $s3 -join ', '

    $s4
}

Write-Output "------Combine files------"

# content
$c1 = Get-Content D:\junk\test1.csv
$c2 = Get-Content D:\junk\test2.csv

# users in both files, could be a better way to do this
$t1 = $c1 | ConvertFrom-Csv
$t2 = $c2 | ConvertFrom-Csv
$users = $t1 | Select SamAccountName

# generate final, combined output
$combined = @()
$combined += CombineSkip1 $c1[0] $c2[0]

$c2PropCount = ($c2[0] -split ',').Count - 1
$filler = (', ""' * $c2PropCount)

for ($i = 1; $i -lt $c1.Count; $i++){
    $user = $c1[$i].Split(',')[0]
    $u2 = $c2 | where {([string]$_).StartsWith($user)}
    if ($u2)
    {
        $combined += CombineSkip1 $c1[$i] $u2
    }
    else
    {
        $combined += ($c1[$i] + $filler)
    }
}

# write to output and file
Write-Output $combined
$combined | Set-Content -Path D:\junk\test3.csv -Force
```

Comment: The only thing missing is the concatenation of the column titles (the first line is $null). But I can use the code snippet (shown in my answer) I have for this. Performance, seems fine. I will test both algorithms when I get to work tomorrow (on larger scale files with over 300,000 records) and let you know the timestamps. This will basically be run weekly.

Comment: Looks good. There is just one other thing (and this is my fault, i just updated the expected output in the question), the records need to be added if they exists in the 1st file, and if they don't exist in the second, those values need to be null. The other thing I noticed in the result file, for some reason when I open the file in excel, it has the entire row open in 1 cell. If I open it in notepad, it looks pretty much the same (with the exception of the records found in file 1 with file 2 column null values) as is with my file (only my file opens in excel with values in their own cells)

Comment: Updated your code in my answer, if you edit yours to give the same results, I'll edit mine out. Then we will just need to solve that last problem where the records are stuffed in 1 cell (opened as excel). Thanks again for spending time on this.

Comment: Solved the record stuffed into 1 cell issue. Just update your code to match the snippet in my answer, and I'll give you the +1 and check for the answer :)

Comment: Updated code to use all rows in 1st file, and matching rows in 2nd.  Enjoy.

Comment: FYI, you just need to remove the whitespace in `$filler = (', ""' * $c2PropCount)`. This stops the quotes from showing up in the cell when opened as excel. Other than that works great :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compare-object` for that purpose. Use `-property samaccountname` with it. For example:

```
$a = 1,2,3,4,5
$b = 4,5,6,7
$side = compare-object $a $b
switch ($side){
'<=' {is not in $a}
'=>' {is not in $b}
'==' { is on both sides}
}
```

When you have all the data in your output-variable, trow it at `convertto-csv` and write it in a file

Comment: output gives a blank file (updated my code for review in question).

Answer (score 0):

After an entire day, I finally came up with something that works...

```
...
```

## Edit

Reason: breaking the inner loop and removing the found element from the array will be much faster when merging files with thousands of records...

```
Function GetTitlesFromFileToBeMerged
{
    Param ($csvFile)

    [String]$fileToBeMergedTitles = Get-Content $fileToBeMerged -TotalCount 1

    [String[]]$fileToBeMergedTitles = ($fileToBeMergedTitles -replace "`",`"", "|").Trim()
    [String[]]$fileToBeMergedTitles = ($fileToBeMergedTitles -replace "`"", "").Trim()
    [String[]]$fileToBeMergedTitles = ($fileToBeMergedTitles -replace "SamAccountName", "").Trim()

    [String[]]$listOfColumnTitles = $fileToBeMergedTitles.Split('|',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

    Write-Output $listOfColumnTitles
}

$baseFile = 'D:\Scripts\Powershell\Tests\base.csv'
$fileToBeMerged = 'D:\Scripts\Powershell\Tests\lookup.csv'
$baseFileCsvContents = Import-Csv $baseFile
$baseFileContents = Get-Content $baseFile
$fileToBeMergedCsvContents = Import-Csv $fileToBeMerged
[System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]]$fileToBeMergedContents = Get-Content $fileToBeMerged
$resultsFile = 'D:\Scripts\Powershell\Tests\MergedResults.csv'
$resultsFileContents = @()

[String]$baseFileTitles = $baseFileContents[0]
[String]$fileToBeMergedTitles = (Get-Content $fileToBeMerged -TotalCount 1) -replace "`"SamAccountName`",", ""
$resultsFileContents += $baseFileTitles + "," + $fileToBeMergedTitles

[String]$lineMatchNotFound = ""
$arrayFileToBeMergedTitles = GetTitlesFromFileToBeMerged $fileToBeMerged
For ($valueNum = 0; $valueNum -lt $arrayFileToBeMergedTitles.Length; $valueNum++)
{
    $lineMatchNotFound += ",`"`""
}

$baseLineCounter = 1
$baseFileCsvContents | ForEach-Object {
    $baseSameAccountName = $_.SamAccountName
    [String]$baseLineInFile = $baseFileContents[$baseLineCounter]

    $lineMatchCounter = 1
    $lineMatchFound = ""
    :inner
    ForEach ($line in $fileToBeMergedContents) {
        If ($line -like "*$baseSameAccountName*") {
            [String]$lineMatchFound = "," + ($line -replace '^"[^"]*",', "")
            $fileToBeMergedContents.RemoveAt($lineMatchCounter)
            break inner
        }; $lineMatchCounter++
    }

    If (!($lineMatchFound))
    {
        [String]$lineMatchFound = $lineMatchNotFound
    }

    $mergedLine = $baseLineInFile + $lineMatchFound
    $resultsFileContents += $mergedLine
    $baseLineCounter++
}

ForEach ($line in $resultsFileContents)
{
    Write-Host $line
}

$resultsFileContents | Set-Content $resultsFile -Force
```

I'm very sure this is not the best approach and there is something better that would handle this much faster. If anyone has any ideas, I'm open to them. Thanks.