# Break out of inner loop only in nested loop

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to implement a break so I don't have to continue to loop when I got the result xxxxx times.

```
$baseFileCsvContents | ForEach-Object {
    # Do stuff
    $fileToBeMergedCsvContents | ForEach-Object {
        If ($_.SamAccountName -eq $baseSameAccountName) {
            # Do something
            break
        }
        # Stop doing stuff in this For Loop
    }
    # Continue doing stuff in this For Loop
}
```

The problem is, that break is exiting both `ForEach-Object` loops, and I just want it to exit the inner loop. I have tried reading and setting flags like `:outer`, however all I get is syntax errors.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You won't be able to use a named loop with ForEach-Object, but can do it using the ForEach keyword instead like so:

```
$OuterLoop = 1..10
$InnerLoop = 25..50

$OuterLoop | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Verbose "[OuterLoop] $($_)" -Verbose
    :inner
    ForEach ($Item in $InnerLoop) {
        Write-Verbose "[InnerLoop] $($Item)" -Verbose
        If ($Item -eq 30) {
            Write-Warning 'BREAKING INNER LOOP!'
            BREAK inner
        }
    }
}
```

Now whenever it gets to 30 on each innerloop, it will break out to the outer loop and continue on.

Comment: Bummer. There is a lot of complicated stuff going on within `ForEach-Object` loops (actual code can be viewed here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019303/how-to-merge-all-contents-in-two-csv-files-where-records-match-off-1-column/36025970#36025970). If I were to change `ForEach-Object` to `ForEach`, it will break the script. Looks like I won't be able to use the break...

Comment: Actually I take that back, I was able to change it to a ForEach, and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I get     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException with `:inner` in PS5

Answer (score 3):

Using the return keyword works, as "ForEach-Object" takes a scriptblock as it's parameter and than invokes that scriptblock for every element in the pipe.

```bsh
    1..10 | ForEach-Object {
        $a = $_
        1..2 | ForEach-Object {
            if($a -eq 5 -and $_ -eq 1) {return}
            "$a $_"
        }
        "---"
    }
```

Will skip "5 1"

Comment: That works in PS5 whereas the other answer with namedloop and foreach instead of foreach-object does not.